# Mock a concrete class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I know that it is not possible to Mock a concrete class but only interfacecs and abstract classes.
Is there any way or any pattern to skirt this?

For example I have the following classes that do not implement any interface. I don't want to create a new instance of C since it will take lot of time in my unit test, how can I mock it and do unit test on Foo()?

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Foo(){}
}

public class C:A
{
    public C()
    {
        // construction takes lot of time    
    }

    public override void Foo()
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you want to test class `C` you have to create an instance of it first. However you CAN mock usual classes. However it´s not recommended because the actual methods are executed instead of your fake-implementations - at least as ling as these methods are non-virtual.

Comment: If `C.Foo` is independent of the work that gets done in `C`'s constructor (which it sounds like it is) then maybe you could a) move the slow-running stuff out of the constructor into a separate `Initialise()` method, or b) move the body of Foo() into a static method called from Foo, and test the static method from your unit test instead.

Comment: This is a legacy code that cannot be refactored :-(

Comment: If it's legacy code that can't be changed, why are you writing unit tests for it?  What are you going to do if the tests show that the code is *broken*?

Comment: Good question! Actually this is a company requirement to have 90% of the code to be unit test, this is a way to show to the customers that the product is reliable, testable....

Comment: In general, code that wasn't written with testability in mind is very hard -if not impossible- to unit test properly. So if your requirements are to add unit tests to a codebase without changing the production code itself, I'd suggest to go have a chat with your tech lead :)

Comment: I don't think that such comments can help in some way to solve  the question I asked. I agree that the requirements are not logic or whatever you want to call them. But those are the requirements I got and if you do not know the solution (if there is at all), please do not reply such offensive answers. And putting -1 to the question is incorrect because leaving aside the reason of this post, the question itself is meaningful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer I work at Typemock.

> I know that it is not possible to Mock a concrete class but only
>   interfaces and abstract classes

With [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com/) you can mock everything, from abstract classes and interfaces to sealed and static classes.

I changed your example a little:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual int Foo() { return 0; }
}

public class C : A
{
    public C()
    {
        // construction takes lot of time    
    }

    private int Bar()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    public override int Foo()
    {
        return Bar() + 1;
    }
}

[TestClass] 
public class Collections
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void FakingWithIsolatorExample()
    {
        var fakeC = Isolate.Fake.Instance<C>();

        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeC.Foo()).CallOriginal();
        Isolate.NonPublic.WhenCalled(fakeC, "Bar").WillReturn(10);

        int result = fakeC.Foo();

        Assert.AreEqual(11, result);
    }
}
```

Comments:

1. The ctor of C was ignored.
2. The real implementation of Foo was called and tested
3. A return value was assigned to private method of C.
4. No changes in your code and additional levels of indirection were needed.